# How to use google-api-services-datastore-protobuf with SBT or Maven?

Tags: java, maven, sbt, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use google-api-services-datastore-protobuf (see https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/downloads) with SBT, but it gave me these errors:

```
[warn] io problem while parsing ivy file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-datastore-protobuf/v1beta1-rev1-1.0.0-rc1/google-api-services-datastore-protobuf-v1beta1-rev1-1.0.0-rc1.pom: Impossible to load parent for file:/Applications/play-2.1.1/framework/../repository/cache/com.google.apis/google-api-services-datastore-protobuf/ivy-v1beta1-rev1-1.0.0-rc1.xml.original. Parent=com.google.apis#google-api-services-datastore-protobuf-parent;v1beta1-rev1-1.0.0-rc1
[warn]  module not found: com.google.apis#google-api-services-datastore-protobuf;v1beta1-rev1-1.0.0-rc1
```

I'm not very familiar with SBT yet so I also tried it with maven but I got similar results:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf:jar:v1beta1-rev2-1.0.1: Could not find artifact com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf-parent:pom:v1beta1-rev2-1.0.1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

It looks like the parent pom is missing or something. Is there a way to work around it or to ignore the missing parent?

Comment: I'm getting the same result after `libraryDependencies += "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-datastore-protobuf" % "v1beta1-rev2-1.0.1"`, so I'm assuming there's something wrong with their pom. I can't find [google-api-services-datastore-protobuf-parent](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgoogle-api-services-datastore-protobuf-parent). I'd suggest you contact Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent pom was indeed missing, but this is fixed [now](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.apis%7Cgoogle-api-services-datastore-protobuf-parent%7Cv1beta1-rev2-1.0.1%7Cpom).

See this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/13) for more details.